# ipad app won't rotate in IOS6

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a UISplitViewController ipad app.  It uses a mainwindow.xib and my subclassed RootView and DetailView controllers.  It autorotates properly in all ioses up to 5.1.

I know the interface changed for ios6.  When I add the new rotation methods to my detail and rootview classes it still does not rotate.

My supportedInterfaceOrientations method is called, but shouldAutorotate is never called.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

(Always learning that no one can mess you around as badly as another programmer. Thanks Apple.)
Gerry

Comment: Stupid question:  Did you toggle the icons in the Xcode project settings to enable the rotated orientations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [iOS 6 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/):

> Autorotation is changing in iOS 6. In iOS 6, the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of `UIViewController` is deprecated. In its place, you should use the `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` and `shouldAutorotate` methods.
>
> More responsibility is moving to the app and the app delegate. Now, iOS containers (such as `UINavigationController`) do not consult their children to determine whether they should autorotate. By default, an app and a view controller’s supported interface orientations are set to `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` for the iPad idiom and `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown` for the iPhone idiom.
>
> A view controller’s supported interface orientations can change over time—even an app’s supported interface orientations can change over time. The system asks the top-most full-screen view controller (typically the root view controller) for its supported interface orientations whenever the device rotates or whenever a view controller is presented with the full-screen modal presentation style. Moreover, the supported orientations are retrieved only if this view controller returns YES from its `shouldAutorotate` method. The system intersects the view controller’s supported orientations with the app’s supported orientations (as determined by the Info.plist file or the app delegate’s `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method) to determine whether to rotate.
>
> The system determines whether an orientation is supported by intersecting the value returned by the app’s `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method with the value returned by the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method of the top-most full-screen controller.
>
> The `setStatusBarOrientation:animated:` method is not deprecated outright. It now works only if the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method of the top-most full-screen view controller returns 0. This makes the caller responsible for ensuring that the status bar orientation is consistent.

I know that's a mouthful but you might also want to check the supported interface orientations sheet in your project's settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The real problem was: my code contained [window addSubview:spliteViewController.view]; in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  Changing it to window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController; fixed the problem.

Comment: Ah, gotchya. So, sounds like there was some view controller specific stuff that might not have been getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up a notification when orientation changed.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                            name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then implement the rotation inside orientationChanged function.

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {}
```